# easy timer to start timing on a page,will not start the timing

Tags: timer

Good morning
I am working on the memory came js challenge.When the page loads and a card is clicked the timer should start.I was referred to the EasyTimer.js (https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/) which seems great,short code and I saw it working for other people.Even if i follow step by step the example I am getting the error that Timer is not defined.Yes Indeed I haven't definer timer somewhere else,as far as i understood if I add the script I will not have to define it separately.I will share my code hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.I am a beginner

```js
var timer = new Timer();
 timer.start();
 timer.addEventListener("secondsUpdated", function (e) {
  $("#timer").html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
 });
 
 function toggleCard() {
    
    // start the timer when first card is opened
    if (startGame == false) {
        startGame = true;
        timer.start();
    }
    
    if (openCard.length === 0) {
        $(this).toggleClass("show open").animateCss('flipInY');
        openCard.push($(this));
        disableCLick();
    }
    else if (openCard.length === 1) {
        // increment moves
        updateMoves();
        $(this).toggleClass("show open").animateCss('flipInY');
        openCard.push($(this));
        setTimeout(matchOpenCard, 1100);
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="moves">3 Moves</span> </br> 
            <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>  --> here is the timer
            <div class="restart">
          <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
         </div>
          
          .....
          
          
          
        <script src="dist/easytimer.min.js"></script>   -->file downloaded in my pc                                                                    and the path is                                                                             correct
```

I have tried using the src as the online link to the easytimer but I am getting the same error
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will not delete the quesition as it might be useful for somebody
I had to add an extra script to the index file

```
<script>
    var timerInstance = new Timer();
    </script>
```

it has to be as it is, var timerInstance can not be replaced with your own variable

Thank you